# Multiple Consumption of single stream

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-stream

I want to know if its possible that multiple functions can consume single stream in node.js. If yes How can this done? Is it possible to pipe to multiple destinations?

I want to use the stream in two different functions which are parallel. I am doing the parallel flow using the async module. So will it possible to say issue the pipe() statement inside each of these functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have the first handler consuming it be a stream itself, then pass it through to the second handler.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum or design a "tee" that maintains multiple output streams and just writes data from the input stream to each output.

Comment: Wait, nvm. You can pipe streams to as many places you want - it's dead simple.

Comment: Are you sure I can pipe it to as many streams as I want?

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra lol, I was wrong and confident about it. I'm a Node maintainer and actually maintain this code now. I ran into this answer again after I figured it might be a good idea to add `tee` to Node streams (9 years late). Sorry for my dumb, objectively false comments!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes**, it's possible, easy and common. The following is a piped data stream from a single source to multiple sources. It shows you the one anonymous callback function that gets placed on the event loop that contains the write function streams that do the actual write work:

```
var fs  = require('fs');

var rs1 = fs.createReadStream ('input1.txt');                      
var ws1 = fs.createWriteStream('output1.txt');     
var ws2 = fs.createWriteStream('output2.txt');

rs1.on('data', function (data) {                                  
  console.log(data.toString('utf8'));                              
  ws1.write('1: ' + data);                                       
  ws2.write('2: ' + data);                                       
});
```

An easier way is to use the `.pipe()` functions.

```
var fs  = require('fs');

var rs1 = fs.createReadStream ('input1.txt');                      
var ws1 = fs.createWriteStream('output1.txt');     
var ws2 = fs.createWriteStream('output2.txt');

rs1.pipe(ws1);
rs1.pipe(ws2);
```

The `.pipe()` allows you to do nifty things like pipeline chaining in the future for pipeline manipulation, very similar to the unix concept of something like `du . | sort -rn | less` where you can use multiple pipes to handlers.

Comment: I am using stream in two different functions in parallel flow in async module. So if I did the pipe in two different functions it would still work ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the details that I have wrote in the comment. So please update your answer too

Comment: var ws1 = fs.createWriteStream('output1.txt');     
var ws2 = fs.createWriteStream('output2.txt');
you are creating 2 objects, i am something very expensive as the data source, a websocket connection from an external server that I cannot create multiple times