# How to clone a readable stream

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I have a stream i am trying to submit the same stream to two different destinations. The first destination is to AWS S3, the second destination is to some other backend via a http request.

```
const document = fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() + "/test/resources/" + "id/document.jpg");

const s3Response = await submitToS3(document);

const backendResponse = await submitToBackend(document);
```

From what i understand a stream can only be read once. How can i send the same stream to two different destinations.

I thought about cloning the stream but simply creating a new variable and assigning the stream to that variable does not work.

Answer (score 4):

you can check this npm module out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/readable-stream-clone

```
npm install readable-stream-clone
```

```
const fs = require("fs");
const ReadableStreamClone = require("readable-stream-clone");
 
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('text.txt');
 
const readStream1 = new ReadableStreamClone(readStream);
const readStream2 = new ReadableStreamClone(readStream);
 
const writeStream1 = fs.createWriteStream('sample1.txt');
const writeStream2 = fs.createWriteStream('sample2.txt');
 
readStream1.pipe(writeStream1)
readStream2.pipe(writeStream2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Raghavendra's answer suggests a good potential direction. You can combine multiple pipes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957525/multiple-consumption-of-single-stream) with S3 pipe implementation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336050/pipe-a-stream-to-s3-upload).

For the `submitToBackend` part, not sure exactly what your implementation looks like, but assuming you can pipe to an HTTP request of some sort...

Example:

```
var fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const rs = fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() + "/test/resources/" + "id/document.jpg");

function uploadFromStream(s3) {
  var pass = new stream.PassThrough();

  var params = {Bucket: BUCKET, Key: KEY, Body: pass};
  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err, data);
  });

  return pass;
}

rs.pipe(uploadFromStream(s3));

// Just guessing at your submitToBackend implementation:
const backendWs = request.post("http://example.com/docs");

// However it works, if you can get to a stream.Writable, you can now pipe the same stream.Readable:
rs.pipe(backendWs);
```

Comment: submitToBackend is an async function i need to wait for a response

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect that i the functions are promises.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I see, but [createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) itself does not return a promise but rather an instance of `fs.ReadStream`. Maybe that's the only problem?

Comment: No i have a stream coming, createReadStream is correct. The stream then gets passed to s3 and http request

Comment: I'm confused. Your code snippet has `await fs.createReadStream`, but you and I are both agreeing that `createReadStream` returns a stream, not a promise. But `await` is for promises (async functions). I think that could be the source of your problem. But perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Yeah sorry i shouldint need to await fs.createReadStream, ive updated that